# Do I need to Download the complete Blockchain before BTC will reflect under amount after running importprivkey? Current Version being used is V22

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have done the importprivkey as per instructions.
I can see the transactions under the transaction Tab, but I do not see my BTC under overview balance.
I do not see the address Tab also as per Wiki Instruction either.
Synchronizing with network currently on 1 year and 48 weeks behind.
All my transactions was before 2020.
Will my BTC only reflect once full Blockchain downloaded and synced with network?

Answer (score 1):

The spendable funds should start being reflected in the balance whenever the transaction is processed while your node is aware of the private key. Since your wallet is already showing you the transaction, it sounds as if the key was present when the transaction was processed. I would suggest to wait for the initial synchronization to finish, during rescans and sync the wallet may still be showing outdated information until it has caught up with the chaintip.

Generally, a node will automatically rescan the blockchain after importing a key (unless you disable it explicitly, e.g. because you want to import multiple keys before rescanning once). If the key's creation date is known, it will only scan the blockchain after that date.

Comment: Importing itself will trigger a rescan (unless you explicitly disable) of the part of the chain after they (claimed) key birthdate.

Comment: @ Murch & Pieter.
Thank you for your answers, really appreciate the feedback. Please excuse as I am very new to the Bitcoin Core GUI Platform and process.
1. Should I wait for the complete networking Syncronizing before doing an importprivkey again? Currently 1 year & 22 Weeks behind and syncing slowly.
2. Since I did the importprivkey more than a week ago already, do I need to run importprivkey command again or just run a rescan in Console?
3. Do I wait for the Syncronizing with Network to complete before running Rescan?

Comment: 4.  Is there a command to rescan only the blocks already syncronized with network(Downloaded)? Then last but not least: Is there a way for me to check my BTC against my privkey. I see my BTC on Blockchain Explorer using Address, but now concerned about the link between my BTC Address & my privkey.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: 1. I'd suggest waiting before doing another import. 2. No need to run import again unless you have more (different) things to import. 3. You do not need to rescan. 4. By definition you can only **re**scan what you already have. If you have more questions, either update the question asked here, or ask new ones.

Comment: @ConradS69: It'll probably be fine when it's finished synchronizing, if not feel free to bring your follow-up questions here. :) It is highly unlikely that there is a problem connecting your address and private key, especially since your transaction is already showing up in your wallet. You can look up your ADDRESS on blockexplorers to confirm that your funds are unspent, but please DO NOT try to import your PRIVATE key in any websites, you may lose your funds if you do.